# Convert JsonArray into Spark Dataset<Row> without an intermediate pojo

Tags: java, apache-spark, gson

From a http call I receive a Json with the following format

```
{
  "name": "foo",
  "version": 1,
  "uploadDate": "2023-04-17",
  "data": [
    {
      "abc": "123",
      "xyz": "",
      "alpha": "4"
    },
     {
      "abc": "456",
      "xyz": "",
      "alpha": "1"
    },
     {
      "abc": "679",
      "xyz": "",
      "alpha": "2"
    },
     {
      "abc": "890",
      "xyz": "",
      "alpha": "5"
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like to extract the `data` element, turn it into a `Dataset<Row>` and persist it to a parquet format file.

If I call this json String `responseBody`, I'm extracting the `data` element with

```
  JsonObject responseBodyObject = new JsonParser().parse(responseBody).getAsJsonObject();
  String dataString = new Gson().toJson(responseBodyObject.get("data"));
```

It already seems a bit wasteful to me to get the string to object to string again. I'm doing this because I will feed it to `spark.read().json(string)`.

My end goal is to convert `data` into a Spark `Dataset<Row>` with the following structure :

```
| abc | xyz | alpha |
---------------------
| 123 |     | 4     |
| 456 |     | 1     |
| 679 |     | 2     |
| 890 |     | 5     |
```

Is it possible to do it without creating a POJO object that match the objects in the json list ? Can I just work with a JsonElement or JsonArray ? I would rather avoid making a new type for each http endpoint (don't want to change that code everytime the endpoint change the structure, as the paint isn't quite dry yet on that side), and I'm going to immediately write that Dataset to a parquet file anyway, I'm not going to do any manipulation of those data. So I felt like a vague type like Row was good enough.

I am not very familiar with spark, how would you go about this ?

Edit : grammar + a bit of extra info about why I don't want a POJO

Comment: What I would try to do is to parse data directly from the request stream using one of the available JSON streaming APIs and transforming it into the desired format on the fly; if you could stream the result too that would be even better for the memory footprint of the application. For reading JSON in a streaming way see e.g. [this (Jackson)](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-streaming-api) and [this (JSONP)](https://javaee.github.io/tutorial/jsonp004.html).

Comment: This piece is going to fetch json files that are typically less than 1.5Kb of data a couple times a month, so I am not too concerned with memory footprint or performance. I can indeed get the `data` field from the stream directly, I will modify my code for this. Still not sure about the conversion to spark though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i am trying to solve(scala language) by just by load json data like

```
val df = spark.read.format("json").option("multiline","True").load("path")

df.show()

+--------------------+----+----------+-------+
|                data|name|uploadDate|version|
+--------------------+----+----------+-------+
|[[123, 4, ], [456...| foo|2023-04-17|      1|
+--------------------+----+----------+-------+

df.printSchema()
root
 |-- data: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- abc: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- alpha: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- xyz: string (nullable = true)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- uploadDate: string (nullable = true)
 |-- version: long (nullable = true)
```

that data will be show as dataset
but you can explode the data in familiar. so

```
 val df1 = df.withColumn("data",explode($"data")).select("data.*","name","version","uploadDate) 
    df1.show()
```

Output will be look like this

```
+---+-----+---+----+----------+-------+
|abc|alpha|xyz|name|uploadDate|version|
+---+-----+---+----+----------+-------+
|123|    4|   | foo|2023-04-17|      1|
|456|    1|   | foo|2023-04-17|      1|
|679|    2|   | foo|2023-04-17|      1|
|890|    5|   | foo|2023-04-17|      1|
+---+-----+---+----+----------+-------+
```

if you dont want to add extra column so you can modify the code like

```
val df1 = df.withColumn("data",explode($"data")).select("data.*") 
    df1.show()
```

Output will be as you want

```
+---+-----+---+
|abc|alpha|xyz|
+---+-----+---+
|123|    4|   |
|456|    1|   |
|679|    2|   |
|890|    5|   |
+---+-----+---+
```

in java language through

```
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.*;

// Assuming the input DataFrame is named "df"
DataFrame df1 = df.withColumn("data", explode(col("data")))
                  .select("data.*");
df1.show();
```

Comment: Thanks for the super clear explanation. I will try this as soon as I come back from holidays and keep you posted